# Fitting a line to the outermost plot on a graph

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics, nonlinear-analysis

I am plotting the nonlinear regression on some fatigue data. My goal is to create a line that adheres to the slope line (in red). This line should sit beneath the lowest point on the left side of the graph.

[image: What I would like to have]

I asked over on stackoverflow and was given a reasonable answer. But that answer only allows the line to pass through the lowest rightmost point. I am wondering what ways mathematically can this be achieved? I have many different plots that I need to apply this logic too.

the equation I am using is $A*N^B$ where B is a constant and N is the length of cycles and A is the mean of the `y` values.

What I have tried. Standard deviation to find the z value and therefore farthest value under the left side of the fitted line. I then shifted the fit line down to this value. However it did not give me consistent results.

I also obtained the Convex Hull and tried to determine which point was most to the left and down but this also didn't work.

Comment: As David G. Stork explained, part of your problem is its very definition. If you need help with defining, you can state what your higher goal is?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:random-graphs].

Answer (score 4):

Your line is not uniquely defined.  Which of the two lines here do you prefer and how would you unambiguously specify it in the general case?

[image]

***For the OP***:  State precisely which two points in the below data set define the line you seek, and also state *precisely and unambiguously* why you don't want the neighboring two points.

Which two points are "outermost"?

[image]

Comment: The blue line. Right now my idea is to use the current slope obtained by Paris' Law, but have that line fit to the lower leftmost points.

Comment: Sorry... your "answer" does not answer the question in the general case... and Paris' Law (from crack growth!) doesn't help at all.

Comment: unambiguously specify in the general case is confusing for me. do you mean this? $[x_1, y_1], [x_2, y_2]$

Comment: State a mathematical equation that will take all the data points and choose the two that will define your desired "lowest-left" points.  The central problem is that there can be many points that are "lowest left."  (I'll post another data set to illustrate that fact.)

Comment: That is my issue. Trying to determine which points are the "lowest-left" points. I originally tried by connecting two points $ [x_min, y_max], [x_max, y_min] $ This only worked for graphs with clear outliers. 

I think the best way to solve my problem may be using the fitted curve I already have. Another approach would be to find all points that are "outliers" and connect those. However, this will create a very "straight" line instead of a sloped line as desired.

Comment: I'm sorry but you simply don't understand that you haven't specified a method for *choosing* the outliers.  (And saying "that is my issue" means we simply cannot help you.).  I'm done here... over and out.